# Clear cache or cookies when user logout

Tags: php, caching

I have a problem with my Website when users sign out.

When I press the Logout button, the account logs out without problems but users remain logged in but in the form of Visitors. This means that they stay connected to the account but it's like a visitor and they view their own profile, where they can send messages to them.
**What I noticed is that if you press CTRL + F5, it disconnects me and redirects me directly to the home page (Login / Register Page).**

This is logout.php file :

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['new_user'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['new_user']);
}

$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
header('Location: http://'.$domain);
```

**What I noticed is that if you press CTRL + F5, it disconnects me and redirects me directly to the home page (Login / Register Page).**

When a user logs in to the account, he is redirected to the "meet" page ([www.test.com/meet](http://www.test.com/meet))

But if I press Logout and then give F5 to refresh the page, it takes me directly to the main page, but if I type in the search bar "www.test.com/MEET" it connects me as a visitor to the previously entered account.

```
case 'meet':
    if ($logged !== true ) {
        showLandingPage();
        exit;
    }   
    $folder = 'meet';
    $page = 'content';
    include('assets/sources/pages.php');
break;
```

And I would like the users to be redirected to the Home Page after logging out and accessing the / meet page ... Which I did but it doesn't work.

I think it's all a matter of Cookies or Cache.

How can I make them delete all cookies and cache data from the browser when they access Logout.

I also tried the "setcookies" option but it doesn't work

In conclusion, what I need is to do something in the logout.php file that once accessed to delete absolutely all browser data and if users access "meet" to redirect them to the Landing Page (ShowLandingPage)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this fits your needings.
You have to clean your cookie and close a session on your `logout.php`

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty($_GET['session'])) {
        setcookie('session_id','',time()-100);
    }
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Nothing...Same problem. Always i must press F5 button . I press logout,than redirect me to the principal page,and when i use F5 redirect me to register/login page....